# Unable to open firebasedynamic links through window.open in IOS Chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

I’m trying to open a firebase dynamic link (which will open an App after) through window.open("thefirebasedynamic link"). This works on IOS Safari, but not in IOS chrome(it used to work). The tab opens and closes by itself without redirecting me to the app.